# C# assignment question

Tags: c#, operators, variable-assignment

In the following snippet:

```
long frameRate = (long)(_frameCounter / this._stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Why is there an additional (long)(...) to the right of the assignment operator?

Comment: What type is `_frameCounter` declared as? In particular, is it non-integral?

Comment: @Steven I am guessing `_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds` is a double, so the result of the division is a double

Comment: Must be a very powerful system if you need to store the framerate as 64 bit compared to the more natural 32 bit. Is this a visual system for aliens? ;^)

Comment: @Steven - private double _frameCounter = 0;

Comment: @Martin: Speak for yourself: anything under 5,000,000,000 FPS flickers terribly for all three of my eyes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The division creates a double-precision floating point value (since `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` is a `double`), so the cast truncates the resulting value to be integral instead of floating point.  You end up with an approximate but whole number of frames-per-second instead of an exact answer with fractional frames-per-second.

If `frameRate` is used for display or logging, the cast might just be to make the output look nicer.

Answer (score 2):

It's an explicit conversion (cast) that converts the result of the division operation to a `long`.

See: [Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of the calculation relates to what types the variables are that are being used.  If the compiler thinks the result type is not a `long` because of the types being acted on, then you need to cast your result.

Note that casting your result may incur loss of accuracy or values.  The bracketed cast `(long)` is an explicit cast and will not generate any errors if, say, you tried to fit "1.234" into a `long`, which could only store "1".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there could be a few reasons:

1. At least one of types in expression is not integer type (I don't think so).
2. Developer wanted to highlighted that result is `long` type (makes the result type clear for reader -- good reason).
3. Developer was not sure what is the result of expression and wanted to make sure it will be `long` (it's better to make sure, that hopes, it will work).

I believe it was 3 :).